# SQL for ordering the actual data in the database table

Tags: sql, odbc, dao

Fairly new to SQL. You can order records returned with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY SalesPrice;
```

Without physical extracting all records, clearing the table, and then re-writing them back in some customised order, is there a way to ask the database driver to re-order the physical data in the database table by some important column or key (e.g. "SalesPrice")?

This would not be desirable for tables with many records or where the data changes regularly, but may make more sense as a maintainenace action where the table is relatively static.

Using DAO and ODBC, though I'm hoping for a general answer that might apply to a variety of databases.

Comment: The way you order data is by specifying an `order by` clause as you have done; otherwise a table is a logical set of unordered rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Period.  Well, there is a nuance to that, which are clustered indexes.  So you can arrange to have the data stored in a particular order.  *However that does not guarantee that `select * from table` will return the results in that order*.

If you are concerned about the performance of such a query, you wnat an index on `(salesprice)`.  Then use `order by salesprice` in the query.